# File Permissions OSX Objective c

Tags: objective-c, macos, file-permissions

After a few hours searching through the Internet I am still not sure how to do this.

I have created a small utility program in Objective C for OS X which is a NSStatusItem with a NSMenu that displays a set of files and folders that resides in a user specified root-folder.
Everything works fine when running the application through XCode, but once deployed nothing seems to be working, only rarely it can create some files.

I need that my utility program can create, write, delete, rename, move, & copy both user created files, folder and hidden files and those created by my program.

Is it because that I haven't got a OS X developer account and therefore cannot sign be deployment?

I have added below the code I use for working with files and folders.

```
//
//  FileUtils.m
//  TODO_List
//
//  Created by Arni Asgeirsson on 28/11/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Arni Asgeirsson. All rights reserved.
//

#import "FileUtils.h"

@implementation FileUtils

+(BOOL)writeFileAtPath:(NSString*)path withContent:(NSString*)content
{
    return [content writeToFile:path atomically:true encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
}

+(NSString*)readFileAtPath:(NSString*)path
{
    return [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
}

+(BOOL)writeFolderAtPath:(NSString*)path
{
    return [FileUtils writeFolderAtPath:path withIntermediateDirectories:NO];
}

+(BOOL)writeFolderAtPathWithIntermediateDirectories:(NSString*)path
{
    return [FileUtils writeFolderAtPath:path withIntermediateDirectories:YES];
}

+(BOOL)writeFolderAtPath:(NSString *)path withIntermediateDirectories:(BOOL)writeAll
{
    if ([path length] > 0) {
        NSString *full_path = path;
        BOOL isDir = false;
        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:full_path isDirectory:&isDir]) {
            if (isDir) {
                [FileUtils deleteFolderAtPath:path];
            }
        }
        return [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:full_path
                                         withIntermediateDirectories:writeAll
                                                          attributes:nil
                                                               error:nil];
    }
    return NO;
}

+(NSArray*)readFolderAtPath:(NSString*)path
{
    if ([path length] > 0)
    {
        NSArray *array = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:NULL];
        if (array) {
            return array;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

+(BOOL)deleteFileAtPath:(NSString*)path
{
    if ([path length] > 0) {
        return [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:NULL];
    }
    return NO;
}

+(BOOL)deleteFolderAtPath:(NSString*)path
{
    if ([path length] > 0) {
        return [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:NULL];
    }
    return NO;
}

+(BOOL)moveFileFromPath:(NSString*)from toPath:(NSString*)to
{
    if ([from length] > 0 && [to length] > 0)
    {
        return [[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath:from toPath:to error:NULL];
    }
    return false;
}

+(BOOL)moveFolderFromPath:(NSString*)from toPath:(NSString*)to
{
    if ([from length] > 0 && [to length] > 0)
    {
        return [[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath:from toPath:to error:NULL];
    }
    return false;
}

+(BOOL)isPathFile:(NSString*)path
{
    BOOL isDir;
    return [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path isDirectory:&isDir] && !isDir;
}

+(BOOL)isPathFolder:(NSString*)path
{
    BOOL isDir;
    return [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir;
}

+(BOOL)copyFileFrom:(NSString*)from to:(NSString*)to
{
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] isReadableFileAtPath:from])
        return [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:to toPath:from error:nil];
    return NO;
}

+(BOOL)copyFolderFrom:(NSString*)from to:(NSString*)to
{
    // TODO: unimplemented
    return NO;
}

@end
```

I tried looking through the example at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/EvenBetterAuthorizationSample/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013768-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2 but it just seemed to be so much code for something that appears so simple, and couldn't figure out how much of it I would need.

Ideally I would like it so that the user does not need to accept that my utility program can work with the files, or at most; only needs to give his/hers consent when the program is being run(start up), ie. only once.

Any hints, advice, answers, directions, links or comments are much appreciated!

Comment: Let us see the code that you call the methods with , I suspect that the current directory is not what you think it is. To debug put logging in to show the actual path values. Also saves time to use [NSFileManager\(https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) rather than produce a duplicate in your code

Comment: Your issue is `error:NULL`.  You have no idea why things are failing.

Comment: At the very least, you should log `NSError` output from methods that have an `error:` argument.  Oh, and it’s *never* right to write `nil` for a non-object pointer (even though it usually works), so `error:nil` is even worse than `error:NULL`, which is itself Not A Good Idea.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I have know added proper error handling and logging to a bundle file to be able to see what goes wrong in the deployed product. Although it turned out that there was nothing wrong with the file permissions. The problem was that I had some nsassertions that I had forgotten to rewrite into code suitable for deployment! My bad...